# Semantic Issue: Cannot use 'throw' with exceptions disabled (It's not warning, It's error)

Tags: xcode

[image]

I have already enabled exceptions on the project and/or target build settings. Project Navigator -> select project or target -> build settings -> Enable Objective-C Exceptions

[image]

but the exceptions are sill disabled.

Also, I watched some related post, but they are talking semantic issue is a warning, but mine is an error, I would be grateful if anyone can solve this problem.

Comment: Can you also put your code in the message and not only a screenshot? Thanks

Comment: @Allan   Sorry i can't make the code layout... <code> static inline std::exception throw_exception (const void *obj)
{
    switch(_zbar_get_error_code(obj)) {
    case ZBAR_ERR_NOMEM:
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    case ZBAR_ERR_INTERNAL:
        throw InternalError(obj);
    case ZBAR_ERR_UNSUPPORTED:
        throw UnsupportedError(obj);
    case ZBAR_ERR_INVALID:
        throw InvalidError(obj);
    case ZBAR_ERR_SYSTEM:
        throw SystemError(obj);
    case ZBAR_ERR_LOCKING:
        throw LockingError(obj);
    case ZBAR_ERR_BUSY:
        throw BusyError(obj); </code>

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a long time  but I had the same issue. I'd like to point out that you might also need to set the "Enable C++ Exceptions" option to "Yes". I set both that option and "Enable Objective-C Exceptions" to "Yes" but to no avail: I still had this problem. Afterwards, I found the option "Other Compiler Flags" and added the option "-fexceptions" and the build succeeded.

My guess is that some other custom settings override the exceptions flag.